# Adapt C# Set/Get class methods into MATLAB class

Tags: matlab

Take the following custom C# class as an example, it represents a point:

```
public class Point
{
    // Attributes:

    double x;
    double y;

    // Constructor:

    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    // Methods:

    public void SetX(double x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void SetY(double y)
    {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double GetX()
    {
        return this.x;
    }

    public double GetY()
    {
        return this.y;
    }
}
```

I would like to adapt this same class to MATLAB. My goal is to implement the Set and Get methods and the Constructor, as similar as possible to the C# way.

I am aware that MATLAB does not allow self-reference, as I read on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5637015/3599179). However, I know that I should problably want to start the class with the following header:

```
classdef Point < handle
```

I read about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17707086/3599179) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12091248/3599179). This statement will declare my custom `Point` class as the MATLAB `handle` class, by having it inherit from the handle superclass. I understand that this will allow me to implement the Set/Get functionality that I am trying to emulate, as well as for the Constructor.

This is what I have so far:

```
classdef Point < handle

    % Attributes
    properties (Access = private)
        x = [];
        y = [];
    end

    % Methods
    methods

        % Constructor: First method, must have the same name as the class.
        function Point(x,y)

        end

        % Set and Get methods:
        function SetX(x)

        end

        ...

    end
end
```

From this point on, I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Just curious, why not to have used directly [C# properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/w86s7x04.aspx) (which you can also mimic with [matlab classes](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/specifying-properties.html) btw).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I didn't know you could call `set` and `get` like that on C#. Regarding MATLAB classes, you were probably referring to this: `function value = get.PropertyName(obj)` right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First as describe in comments to your question, lets first simplify your C# using [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx):

```
public class Point
{
    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
         this.X = x;
         this.Y = y;
    }

    public double X { get; set; }
    public double Y { get; set; }
}
```

Now to create similar class in Matlab you indeed have to create a [`classdef`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/classdef.html) file and if you want to mimic pass by reference you'll have to derive from [`handle`](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/handle-objects.html)  class else object will be passed by value. So using properties your maltab class will look like:

```
classdef Point < handle

    methods
        function [this] = Point(x, y)
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        end
    end

    properties
        X;
        Y;
    end

end
```

Now suppose you need to implement setters/getters for validation purpose for example. Your C# class will then look like:

```
public class Point
{
    public Point(double x, double y)
    {
         this.X = x;
         this.Y = y;
    }

    private double x; // Back-store
    public double X // Setters and getters
    { 
         get 
         { 
             return x; 
         } 
         set 
         {
             if (value < 0.0) { throw new InvalidArgumentException("X must be positive"); }
             x = value;
         } 
    }

    ... same for 'Y' ...
}
```

You can implement similar getter/setter in Matlab using [dependent properties concept](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/access-methods-for-dependent-properties.html). Syntax is quite similar to C# one while a little more over-verbose:

```
classdef Point < handle

    methods
        function [this] = Point(x, y)
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        end
    end

    % Back-store as in C#
    properties(SetAccess=private, GetAccess=private)
        x;
        y;
    end

    % Setters and getters using dependent properties
    properties(Dependent)
        X;
        Y;
    end

    % Definition for setters and getters
    methods
        function [value] = get.X(this)
            value = this.x;
        end
        function [] = set.X(this, value)
            if (value < 0.0), error('X must be positive'); end
            this.x = value;
        end

        ... Same for 'Y' ...

    end

end
```

For further check for similarities *and differences* in object oriented programming concepts and implementations between Matlab and C# I recommand your to read [documentation](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015b/pdf_doc/matlab/matlab_oop.pdf) on Mathworks website.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
function obj Point(x,y)
     obj.x=x;
     obj.y=y;
end

function setX(obj,x)
     obj.x=x;
end

function getX(obj)
     return obj.x;
end
```

And something similar for the rest of the methods.

Then you can use it like this:

```
p1=Point(5,4);
p1.setX(3);
xp1=p1.getX;
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. However, I am not sure if your example is a class at all.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, of course it is not a class as a standalone piece of code. It should go inside the methods part of your class, but as I saw you already had the structure of the class I saw no point in copying it. It looks like I explained myself poorly.

Comment: I was also considering that option, but I needed to confirm. Thanks again.